# ¿Cómo poner formato de moneda en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento poner una cantidad en formato de moneda, intente con `Round(campo, 2)`, pero solo manda dos decimales al final, lo esperado sería:
De `12345` a `$12,345.00`.

Comment: Una variable numérica no tiene formato. O lo conviertes en una cadena (con formato) o el problema es en la capa de visualización de los datos. ¿Desde dónde quieres ver el número con formato?

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho para visualizarlo en un formato Jasper

Comment: Ok, un reporte jasper? si es así deberías resolverlo con las opciones de formato del propio reporte no convirtiéndolo a una cadena, por que de estas forma pierdes la naturaleza numérica del dato y por ejemplo pierdes la capacidad de usarlo en formulas o sumatorias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías hacer un conversión a tipo `MONEY` y luego a `VARCHAR` para poder concatenar el sigo de `$`:

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(12345  AS MONEY), 1))
```

El resultado sería:

> $12,345.00

Answer (score 0):

Existe una mejor forma y sirve para cualquier pais, tan solo cambiando el codigo:

```
 FORMAT('25000','C','En-Us')
 FORMAT(1234567.89, 'C','ja-JP')
```

El resultado: $25,000.00 y ¥1,234,568